# Use UART PIC24FJ64GB002

Tags: pic, c, uart

I am trying to setup a PIC24FJ64GB002 for UART communication in MBLAB using XC16.  I am using the USB CDC demo to communicate with a device, and I am trying to relay that information to an arduino using the PIC.  I am confused as to what frequency the cpu is running at.  I am using an external 8 MHZ crystal, with several bits set in the demo.  Bits relating to the oscillator are set here.

```
#include <p24FJ64GB002.h>
#include "system.h"
#include "usb.h"

/** CONFIGURATION Bits **********************************************/
_CONFIG1(
    WDTPS_PS1 &
    FWPSA_PR32 &
    WINDIS_OFF &
    FWDTEN_OFF &
    ICS_PGx1 &
    GWRP_OFF &
    GCP_OFF &
    JTAGEN_OFF
)

_CONFIG2(
    POSCMOD_HS &
    I2C1SEL_PRI &
    IOL1WAY_OFF &
    OSCIOFNC_ON &
    FCKSM_CSDCMD &
    FNOSC_PRIPLL &
    PLL96MHZ_ON &
    PLLDIV_DIV2 &
    IESO_OFF
)

_CONFIG3(
    WPFP_WPFP0 &
    SOSCSEL_SOSC &
    WUTSEL_LEG &
    WPDIS_WPDIS &
    WPCFG_WPCFGDIS &
    WPEND_WPENDMEM
)

_CONFIG4(
    DSWDTPS_DSWDTPS3 &
    DSWDTOSC_LPRC &
    RTCOSC_SOSC &
    DSBOREN_OFF &
    DSWDTEN_OFF
)

/*********************************************************************
* Function: void SYSTEM_Initialize( SYSTEM_STATE state )
*
* Overview: Initializes the system.
*
* PreCondition: None
*
* Input:  SYSTEM_STATE - the state to initialize the system into
*
* Output: None
*
********************************************************************/
void SYSTEM_Initialize( SYSTEM_STATE state )
{
    //On the PIC24FJ64GB004 Family of USB microcontrollers, the PLL will not power up and be enabled
    //by default, even if a PLL enabled oscillator configuration is selected (such as HS+PLL).
    //This allows the device to power up at a lower initial operating frequency, which can be
    //advantageous when powered from a source which is not gauranteed to be adequate for 32MHz
    //operation.  On these devices, user firmware needs to manually set the CLKDIV<PLLEN> bit to
    //power up the PLL.
    {
        unsigned int pll_startup_counter = 600;
        CLKDIVbits.PLLEN = 1;
        while(pll_startup_counter--);
    }

    switch(state)
    {
        case SYSTEM_STATE_USB_HOST:
            PRINT_SetConfiguration(PRINT_CONFIGURATION_LCD);
            break;

        case SYSTEM_STATE_USB_HOST_CDC_BASIC:
            BUTTON_Enable(BUTTON_USB_HOST_CDC_BASIC);
            PRINT_SetConfiguration(PRINT_CONFIGURATION_LCD);
            break;
    }
}
```

I then use this function to initialize the UART

```
void UART_INIT()
{
   AD1PCFGL = 0xFFFF;
   __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xbf);
   TRISBbits.TRISB15 = 0;
   __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x40);
   RPOR7bits.RP15R = 3;
   U1BRG = 103; //set baud speed
   U1MODE   =   0x8000;  //turn on module
   U1STA    =   0x8400;  //set interrupts
   IEC0bits.U1TXIE = 0;
   IFS0bits.U1RXIF = 0;
   IFS0bits.U1TXIF = 0;
}
```

And this function to transmit a byte

```
void send(char c)
{
   while(U1STAbits.UTXBF == 1);
   U1TXREG = c;
}
```

I am trying to figure out what value FCY should be defined to be.  I assumed that it would be 16 MHZ, (96MHz / 3) / 2 but the code did not work at that setting.  Could there be another problem in the code?

I am making all pins digital and setting the UART pin as an input with this code

```
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xbf);
AD1PCFGL = 0xFFFF;
TRISBbits.TRISB15 = 0;
UART_INIT(9600);
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x40);
```

Finally, I use the functions like this

```
UART_INIT(9600); 

while(1) 
{ 
send('H'); 
send('e'); 
send('l'); 
send('l'); 
send('o'); 
send(' '); 
send('W'); 
send('o'); 
send('r'); 
send('l'); 
send('d'); 
send('\n'); 
}
```

Comment: In your CONFIG2 you have FNOSC_PRIPLL selected. So your CPU is probably being clocked at 48MHz (if you haven't messed with the CPDIV bits in the CLKDIV register).

Comment: But PLLDIV_DIV2 is also set, so isn't the frequency really 24 MHZ, but I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: After Reading The Fine Manual in a little more detail (and paying particular attention to section 8.5), it seems that you're most likely to have a 32MHz CPU clock. The 96MHz PLL requires a 4MHz input (which is why you need PLLDIV_DIV2), and that gets divided by 3 before being fed to the CPU.

Comment: That would mean that the FCY = 32/2 = 16 MHZ except that i tried it and doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diagram would help convey what you're doing. I think this is what you have implemented:

"a device" (USB device) <-> USB <-> PIC24FJ64BG002 (USB host) <-> UART <-> Arduino

Let's take a look at the clock options for this part:

[image]

Let's also look more closely at the USB-specific clock stuff:

[image]

CONFIG2 contains your oscillator-related stuff:

```
_CONFIG2(
POSCMOD_HS &                      
I2C1SEL_PRI &
IOL1WAY_OFF &
OSCIOFNC_ON &
FCKSM_CSDCMD &
FNOSC_PRIPLL &
PLL96MHZ_ON &
PLLDIV_DIV2 &
IESO_OFF
)
```

Recapping what we know:

- Your source crystal is 8 MHz (input from POSC)
- POSCMOD is set to HS Oscillator Mode
- FNOSC is set to Primary Oscillator + PLL
- PLLDIV is set to divide-by-2

Also, from the datasheet:

- The default setting for CPDIV is 0x00, which is divide-by-1 (32 MHz)

So, what's our conclusion? I would say that unless there's other code messing with the bits somewhere, the situation is as is shown in figure 8.2 - HSPLL is running at 32 MHz (96 MHz USB PLL output, divided by three, then divided by one).

And, because we know that

\$ F_{CY} = \dfrac {F_{OSC}}{2} \$

the answer should be 16 MHz.

Now, to your baud rate formula:

```
baud = (FCY/(16*baud))-1;
```

(It's bad practice to have the same variable name on both sides of the equation: the left side should be renamed to BRG or something more like what it is - it's the baud rate generator value, not the baud rate itself.)

If you look up the PIC24 Family Reference Manual for UART, you'll find the values pre-computed for you:

[image]
[image]

By default, BRGH is zero so unless code is messing with it, your baud rate generator should be set to 103 decimal. (Your formula is for BRGH - 0 and with a 16 MHz clock rate agrees with this table.)

I would dare a guess and say that your UART issues, if they persist, aren't clock related...

Comment: I have the same problems, even when just plugging in 103

Comment: The problem was simple, I had forgotten to call the init method which turns on the PLL, but great answer.

Comment: Bingo. At least you have it resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

In PIC24 core, FCY is half the oscillator frequency. With external 8 MHz crystal, multiplied by 4 (PLL), divided by 2 (PLLDIV), and then divided by 2 once again (first sentence) you'll get 8 MHz. Oscillator is also available at REFO pin, you can enable it and measure the frequency directly using counter, oscilloscope, or a logic analyzer.

Comment: I tried that but when running this code, gibberish comes out on the arduino                                                                                           UART_INIT(9600);
    
    while(1)
    {
        send('H');
        send('e');
        send('l');
        send('l');
        send('o');
        send(' ');
        send('W');
        send('o');
        send('r');
        send('l');
        send('d');
        send('\n');
    }

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have greatly explained about configuration settings, my focus is on the code you are using for `UART Communication`. Microchip provides peripheral library functions which you can use directly in your program instead of putting values in registers. Go to `c\Program Files\Microchip\(your compiler)\docs` you will find many documentation for it or try searching for `PIC18/PIC24/PIC32 peripheral library`. I have not worked in PIC24 but the functions are same for all the MCU series like `PIC18` `PIC24` `PIC32`. For example, for UART:

```
OpenUART(): to initialize UART channel.
putsUART(): to send string to your UART
getsUART(): to receive string from UART
putcUART(): to send a char.
getcUART(): to receive a char
```

you can use these functions directly and save your time.!

Demo Code:

```
/*
*
*/
int main()
{
  /*
  *
  */
  OpenUART1( UART_EN | UART_NO_PAR_8BIT | UART_1STOPBIT, UART_RX_ENABLE | UART_TX_ENABLE, (FPB/16/BAUDRATE)-1 );
  while(1)
  {
    putsUART1("Hello World");
  }
}
```

Comment: What header needs to be included to use those functions

Comment: @popgalop To use peripheral library, you need to include `plib.h`

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

- Disable the transmit interrupt and clear TX interrupt flag
- Calculate the U1BRG value yourself and enter it into the register.
- Since you are unsure of the FCY value, try 4M, 8M, 16M, 32M ... until one works.

The code should look like this, rearranged a bit:

```
void UART_INIT()
{
   __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xbf);
   RPOR7bits.RP15R = 3;   // connect uart1 tx to RP15
   //AD1PCFGL = 0xFFFF;  //try the code with and without this line
   __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x40);
   U1BRG = 103;    //set baud value for 9600 (verify)
   IEC0bits.U1TXIE = 0;  //just in case
   IEC0bits.U1RXIE = 0;
   U1MODE   =   0x8000;  //turn on module
   U1STA    =   0x0400;  // enable TX
   IFS0bits.U1TXIF = 0;
   IFS0bits.U1RXIF = 0;
}

void send(char c)
{
   while(U1STAbits.UTXBF);
   U1TXREG = c;
}

void uart_print(const char * str){
    while (*str)
       send(*str++);
}

void main(){
    //initialize clock and other stuff here

    UART_INIT(); 
    //add a delay of 20ms here, just in case

    while(1)
       uart_print("Hello world\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are unsure if your clock is working perfectly just toggle a pin using __delay_us(x) and see if the output waveform on the oscilloscope is right.

and regarding the baud rate the equation has a single mistake (compiler stupidity) , try this :
baud = (FCY/(16.0*baud))-1 . 
when you add ".0" to 16 , you are forcing a float divide , because sometimes the compiler makes optimizations and the result of is not correct if integer is used.
 I faced exactly same issue before and this solved it.

hope that helps